# Is it possible to set up multiple automatic TIMESTAMP columns in MySQL for to track changes made in every column?

Tags: mysql, timestamp, crud

MySQL Database will be being modified using a PHP Crud system, and I need to track when each record was modified.

For example, if my table has 30 rows, and 30 columns, and I want to put a "Last Modified" beside each individual entry, can I somehow set up 30 TIMESTAMP columns related to each existing column to achieve that?

Or is there a better way?

Here's what I basically want:

```
Column 1   C1s TIMESTAMP   Column 2   C2s TIMESTAMP   Column 3   C3s TIMESTAMP...
Red        (lastModified)  Green      (lastModified)  Blue       (lastModified)
Orange     (lastModified)  Purple     (lastModified)  Pink       (lastModified)
Yellow     (lastModified)  Black      (lastModified)  Brown      (lastModified)
... etc
```

Comment: I think you can do this setting the update time from insert/update query or using a trigger

Answer (score 0):

Not with the native MySQL auto initializing `TIMESTAMP`/ `DATETIME` functionality alone.

As of Mysql 5.6.5 you can have as many auto intitializing `TIMESTAMP` (or `DATETIME`) columns as you want, however these work at the level of the ***record***, not column.

What I mean by this is you can auto set any `TIMESTAMP` on creation to the `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.  You can also set the `TIMESTAMP` column to update on modification of the ***RECORD***.   However, **all** columns set to update timestamps on modifcation will update when any column is updated (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html)

Given this, it only makes sense to have at most 2 auto `TIMESTAMP` columns: one for recording the creation date, the other for the modification date.

Here's how you create auto incrementing `timestamp` columns:

```
ALTER TABLE sometable 
   ADD COLUMN created_date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
   ADD COLUMN  modified_date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
                                     ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

There is no way with just the auto timestamp functionality to only update when a specific column is modified.

You'd need to implement a trigger with a custom procedure to accomplish your need.

Comment: @GraemeFindlay  see my edited answer, I added the alter table statement

Comment: Thanks @Ray, I totally understand that the build-in TIMESTAMP functionality won't give me what I need. Can you elaborate on the how I could "trigger a custom procedure" when a modification is made?

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to determine which column changed though. As you have access to the OLD and NEW values, you could check for every field if it changed and if it changed enter a new timestamp into the according field. Something like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER updateTable
BEFORE UPDATE ON tableA
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    IF OLD.field1 != NEW.field1 THEN
        SET NEW.timestamp1 = now()
    END IF;
    IF OLD.field2 != NEW.field2 THEN
        SET NEW.timestamp2 = now()
    END IF;
END
```

I think that might work, but I haven't tested it.

Comment: This is the way to do it. In passing - I have worked on systems which store the entire record (in a separate table) plus a timestamp so that a 'replay' can be effected.

Comment: Ah, I think I understand how the Trigger works. When the database detects that an UPDATE is occurring, it stores the current data, makes the update, and then compares it to the newly modified data. Is that correct? Where is this Trigger code stored? Can I just enter it as an SQL Query through phpMyAdmin?

Comment: Yes, creation of a trigger is just a sql query that you can run in phpMyAdmin. For description on the syntax you can find here with examples. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: I think your code needs a little correction: add `;` after `now()`. @Graeme you can insert this trigger using PhpMyAdmin: you'll find `Triggers` into `Others` menu (Top Right).

Comment: I've been trying to add this Trigger, however the code has errors beyond the semicolon after date().

    CREATE TRIGGER updateTable
    BEFORE UPDATE ON MyTable
    FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN
        IF OLD.Address != NEW.Address THEN
            SET NEW.Address_Timestamp_test = "got it"
        END IF;
    END

The problem is near the "END IF; END" part. Error is:

    #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual     that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to    use near 'END IF
    END' at line 7

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do what you want as a subset of a greater facility would be to implement a change log.  Place a trigger on every table.  In each trigger, write an "audit entry" record into a table which has details determined by the trigger logic:  which field changed, the old value, the new value, and the timestamp when it occurred.

The audit entry could have an autofilled timestamp instead of explicitly managing it.  With a little bit of cleverness, the triggers could feed a common stored procedure which accepts a tablename parameter as well as the other information.

This would provide a complete history of *all* changes, not just the last one.